# Java- How to create hash id from a list of String

Tags: java, string, list, hashcode

I have a list of String. I want to generate one single hash code from all the strings of the list. How can I do that?

Comment: add them to a list and get [list.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--)

Answer (score 5):

If you have a List of objects, you can do

```
List<String> list = ...
int hashCode = list.hashCode();
```

The hashCode uses the contents. There are lots of options for improving the hash code if you need but this is the simplest.

Comment: Does this apply to every Collection children, or just List?

Comment: @JoãoMatos All collections generate a hashCode based on the contents of the elements, keys/values. Note: if you change any element, key or value and this is in a HashSet or a key of a Map this can corrupt that collection.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int hashCode = Objects.hash(list.toArray());
```

Comment: I would make sure this doesn't hash the array instead of the contents.

Comment: @peter it doesn’t, because `toArray()` returns an `Object[]`, which is passed as the whole varargs.

Comment: @peter but I like your answer better :)

Comment: @peter yeah, re DV, although clunky, this is the general answer to hashing a bunch o’ stuff

Comment: Or `Arrays.asList( ... ).hashCode()` for older versions of Java.

Comment: that was my downvote for creating an array when there is no apparent need for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could just take the `hashCode` of the list, but that may be dodgy if you intend to have different implementations of `List` hold the same strings. A more robust solution, that relies only on the strings themselves could be to use [`Arrays#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#hashCode-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
int hash = Arrays.hashCode(list.toArray());
```

Note, however, that this hash code depends on the order of the elements of the array, so if you don't care about the order of the strings in the list, you may want to sort this array so that the same strings produce the same hash code.

Comment: This is better if you don't trust how the List has been implemented, or I would avoid using a List implementation I don't trust.